# The method setOpacity(float) from the type Window is not visible

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm trying to use the method setOpacity but am getting the error

> The method setOpacity(float) from the type Window is not visible

Here is my full code

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class TranslucentWindow {

    public static JDialog frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        frame = new JDialog();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setOpacity(0.15f);
        frame.setLocation(0, 0);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);

    }

}
```

EDIT: My Java version

java version "1.6.0_27"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

And Eclipse compiler was on 1.6 but I changed it to 1.7

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  I think `setOpcity` is only available in Java 7

Comment: Updated the OP with my Java version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window transparency support was added to the public API's in Java 7

Take a look at [How to create a translucent and shaped window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) for more details

> This functionality, which is part of the public AWT package in the JDK
>   7 release, takes three forms, as follows:

If you need to use this functionality in Java 6, update 12 and above introduces the private API `AWTUtilities`, which provides much of the same functionality.

Check out [this](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/02/27/translucent-and-shaped-windows-in-core-java.html) for a basic example

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using java 7. This won't work otherwise. `setOpacity()` isn't part of <= java6

Comment: I changed the code from "JDialog" to "Dialog" but I get the same error and one on the line "frame = new Dialog();"

Comment: `JDialog` extends `Dialog`

Comment: @user2612619 I was completely wrong before because I didn't look carefully enough. I've updated my answer.

Comment: public static JDialog frame extends Dialog; Like that?

Comment: @user2612619 No, `JDialog` extends itself from `Dialog`, meaning that it inherited all the same functionality that `Dialog` has